# A variant of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for integral

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, integral-inequality

[image]

I have encountered the above inequality in a proof, where

- $u(\tau) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$  is any unit vector
- $T_0$ and $t$ is are positive real numbers

The proof states that the inequality follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality; however, it is very different from the following standard Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$\int_{a}^b |f(x)|^2 dx \int_{a}^b |g(x)|^2 dx \geqslant \big|\int_{a}^b f^\star(x)g(x) dx \big|^2.$$

Could you explain how the first inequality can be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(\tau) = \|u^T(\tau)w\|$ and $g(\tau) = 1$, and use
$$
f(\tau)^2 = w^T u(\tau) u^T(\tau) w.
$$

Comment: That is true! Thanks!